# Getting "http-server: command not found" error after installing using NPM

Tags: macos, npm, npm-install, httpserver, macos-mojave

I have installed http-server using "**npm install http-server**" command in my mac machine.

But still I am getting `http-server: command not found` error.

I have checked the path variable using "**echo $PATH**",the result is `usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. I think the path is correct.

Please help to fix this..!

Comment: How are you trying to run that command? Unless you `install -g` it won't be on your global path, you need to call it from `"scripts"` in the package file or access `./node_modules/.bin` explicitly.

Comment: I noticed that I have this issue with all the packages installed locally.

Comment: It's not an issue, that's what's *supposed* to happen. If all of your local npm projects added all of their executables to the path it would be a mess.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean that all packages should be installed globally? If not it should be called from scripts. Right?

Comment: No, I'd suggest installing as few packages globally as possible. Write package scripts for your project, unless this is something you *are* using outside any project. You can also look at [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).